# How this can be achieved "?country=us" for showing geo-targeted contents to website in url?

Tags: web-services, web

When we access some website, the page gives us country level content, when I noticed the url it looks like "?country=in" for India nor "?country=uk" for uk. how do they achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a GET parameter, which you can add to a url.
After the url you put `?` and for any other parameter you would like to add you use `&` like this:

www.sample.com/path?country=uk&city=london

Accessing these parameters depends on what language you use:

PHP example: `echo $_GET['country'];`